# What does this JDBC snippet achieves?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

```
String q = "SELECT attr FROM students foo =? AND bar = ?";
PreparedStatement s= connection.prepareStatement(q);
s.setString(1,"a");
s.setString(2."b");
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
 System.out.println("aba");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("zab");
}
```

I'm not entirely sure, but my interpretation is that it performs query to find "attr" from "students" where foo is something and bar is something. In case of successful results from query it prints out aba, otherwise it will print out zab.

Correct me if i'm wrong.What s.setStrings(1,"a") are for? What exactly question mark stands for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mostly right. If there is **at least one** row in the `students` table, with field `foo='a'` and `bar='b'`, this prints out `aba`, if no such line exists, it prints out `zab`

The question marks and the0 `.setString(1,"a")` statements are closely related. The `?` denotes a parameter (placeholder, if that is more convenient to grasp) to the query, and the `s.set<datatype>()` methods 'fill these in'. The first parameter specifies the parameter to fill in, the second specifies the value.

Recommended reading: [Using PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1):

The question mark in the query represents the values to be added later on. They act as placeholders.

So you prepare the query once and then just set the values using, e.g.,

```
s.setString(1,"a");
```

This sets the first value (aka the first question mark) to a string value of `a`. There are respective functions for other types like, for example, `setInt()` or `setLong()`.